# How can I get Wordpress CPT archives and page templates to work with prettified permalink settings?

Tags: permalinks, page-template, custom-post-type-archives

I'm having very weird issues with my permalinks and template files on [this site](http://ostforsk.screenpartner.no/) I'm building.

I've created several Custom Post Types. These all have archive pages in my template structure named `archive-$posttype.php`
I've also created custom page templates named `page-$name.php` that's located in a folder named `my-templates`.

Here's my issue. When using default permalink settings these pages all work perfectly, but when prettyfying the permalink to `/%postname%/` or any other permalink setting but the default one, they stop working and default to the index template.

I know there's nothing wrong with my code for the CPT as they all have set archive

```
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'publikasjoner', 'with_front' => false ),
'has_archive' => 'publikasjoner',
```

There must be something I'm missing somewhere, but I've never had this issue and I can't find any info on it elsewhere..

Comment: post type archive templates should be named `archive-$posttype.php`

Comment: Sorry, corrected that in the question. My templates are named `archive-$posttype.php`

Comment: Are you sure you have no conflicts with other plugins or functions? Test your CPT archive on clean WordPress install with default theme.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try two things first:

1. Make sure you have flushed the permalinks ( Settings - Permalinks - Update )
2. Make sure you are using an init action hook to create your custom post types (I've forgotten to do this before and had the type of issue you describe)

If that fails, I'd recommend updating your question to include the full declaration of at least one of your custom post types and show the action you are using to set it up.

Comment: Is there a way for me to manually flush the permalinks? Updating from settings doesn't seem to update it. When visiting `/?post_type=publikasjoner` after updating permalinks to `/%postname%/`..

Comment: If you've went into settings - permalinks and selected update, then you should be good on that front. That effectively flushes them manually. If that didn't help, try item (2) noted above.